# Error asking for :key to be placed on <template>

Tags: vue.js, vuejs3

For not having `:key="item.id"` on `<template>`, I'm getting this error:

[image: error1]

But when I do put it on there as such:

```html
<template v-for="item in Object.values(cart)" :key="item.id">
```

…then I get this error:

[image]

Here's the code in question:

```html
          <template v-for="item in Object.values(cart)">
            <tr :key="item.id">
              <td>Digest {{ item.digestId }}</td>
              <td>{{ item.duration_text }} subscription</td>
              <td class="price-cell">${{ roundMoney(item.price, 2) }}</td>
              <td class="trash-cell">
                <fa-icon icon="times-circle" size="lg" @click="removeItem(item)" />
              </td>
            </tr>
            <tr v-if="item.discounts.length" :key="`${item.id}-${item.discounts && item.discounts[0].id}`">
              <td colspan="2">
                <label>Code: {{ item.discounts[0].code }}</label>
              </td>
              <td colspan="2">
                <span class="discount-amount">–${{ item.discounts[0].percent_off }}</span>
              </td>
              <td class="trash-discount-cell">
                <fa-icon icon="times-circle" class="trash" @click="rmDscnt(item.discounts[0])" />
              </td>
            </tr>
          </template>
```

How might I get around this circular-seeming issue?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Vue: template can't be keyed, but can't replace template with div - need the v-for without a wrapper div element, nested v-for loops](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62202741/vue-template-cant-be-keyed-but-cant-replace-template-with-div-need-the-v-f)

Comment: I'd move both the `v-for` and `:key` on to `<tbody>`. You can have multiple `<tbody>` tags

Comment: @Phil, thank you, although I don't think that link answers my question, since it's putting the `v-for` and `:key` on `<table>`, since you're saying it's valid html to have multiple `<tbody>` tags, then I can use that. Though I don't love the idea of messy markup with the extra `<tbody>` tags, if there is no other solution due to Vue's design decisions, I appreciate your solution (I tested and it works). If you add your comment as an answer, I'm happy to accept it.

Answer (score 11):

Although it has been a year since this question, I recently encountered a similar problem in discussions with others and found the reason for the problem. I hope my answer can help other friends who see this answer.

The tag of the questioner is vue3. In vue3, the v-for standard syntax is used on the template tag to write the key on the template tag.  Please see the official document here: https://v3.vuejs.org/guide/list.html#v-for-on-a-template.

as follows:

```html
<template v-for="item in Object.values(cart)" :key="item.id">
```

I think the reason for the infinite loop error of the questioner is that the rules of vue2 and vue3 are used at the same time.
My vue2 project uses the volar plugin also to cause this error. Use v-for on template tag, vue2 and vue3 use two kinds of rules.

vue2: vue/no-v-for-template-key
vue3: vue/no-v-for-template-key-on-child

These two rules conflict with each other.
Here is the official guidance document: https://eslint.vuejs.org/rules/no-v-for-template-key-on-child.html

I did not give a solution, because I am not clear about the other configuration of the questioner, but I think I have found the reason, and hope to help you troubleshoot the problem

Comment: You can turn off eslint rule 'vue/no-v-for-template-key' in vue3.

Answer (score 0):

I recently got this error and was able to fix it by setting up Volar to use Vue 2.7 instead

```
// tsconfig.json
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    // ...
  },
  "vueCompilerOptions": {
    "target": 2.7,
    // "target": 2, // For Vue version <= 2.6.14
  }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Vue use template tag to know if is a component also like react you must return one element try this:

```
      <template>
        <div>
         <section v-for="item in Object.values(cart)">
        <tr :key="item.id">
          <td>Digest {{ item.digestId }}</td>
          <td>{{ item.duration_text }} subscription</td>
          <td class="price-cell">${{ roundMoney(item.price, 2) }}</td>
          <td class="trash-cell">
            <fa-icon icon="times-circle" size="lg" @click="removeItem(item)" />
          </td>
        </tr>
        <tr v-if="item.discounts.length" :key="`${item.id}-${item.discounts && item.discounts[0].id}`">
          <td colspan="2">
            <label>Code: {{ item.discounts[0].code }}</label>
          </td>
          <td colspan="2">
            <span class="discount-amount">–${{ item.discounts[0].percent_off }}</span>
          </td>
          <td class="trash-discount-cell">
            <fa-icon icon="times-circle" class="trash" @click="rmDscnt(item.discounts[0])" />
          </td>
        </tr>
        </section>
        </div>
      </template>
```

Answer (score -1):

As explained by others, Vue.js will use the  tag for rendering and compilation, it will not really exist in the DOM. The keys are required so that Vue's diffing algorhythm can tell the different instances of the components apart.

That said, after check your example I realized you do not need  here, I assume your  is inside a  or  tag, so you can simply v-for the  itself.

Example:

```
    <table>
    <tbody>
        <tr v-for="item in Object.values(cart)" :key="item.id">
            <td>Digest {{ item.digestId }}</td>
            <td>{{ item.duration_text }} subscription</td>
            <td class="price-cell">${{ roundMoney(item.price, 2) }}</td>
            <td class="trash-cell">
                <fa-icon icon="times-circle" size="lg" @click="removeItem(item)" />
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr v-if="item.discounts.length" :key="`${item.id}-${item.discounts && item.discounts[0].id}`">
            <td colspan="2">
                <label>Code: {{ item.discounts[0].code }}</label>
            </td>
            <td colspan="2">
                <span class="discount-amount">–${{ item.discounts[0].percent_off }}</span>
            </td>
            <td class="trash-discount-cell">
                <fa-icon icon="times-circle" class="trash" @click="rmDscnt(item.discounts[0])" />
            </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

I will take the chance to give you another tip I use on my own codes, instead of using record attributes, for example, 'item.id' I use the index generated by the looping that will always have a sequence avoiding duplicated errors and the most important, it will always have a valid value.

Example:

```
<tr v-for="(item, index) in Object.values(cart)" :key="`items_${index}`">
```

If it helps you, please, mark as answered.

Happy coding!